# Wire Harness Schematic : Use of Brackets between conductors

Tags: connector, wire, cable-assemblies

[image]

I have looked add several documents concerning themself with wire harness schematics. I am having a hard time identifying the meaning of the brackets between several individual conductors tied to a black dot. Has anyone come across such symbols and do they affect the physical layout of wires, similar twisted pairs or shielding?

Comment: My guess would be that those conductors are shielded and the shields are connected to the "R" conductor.